# Как заставить Chrome увидеть touchscreen на Windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, touch

У меня есть терминал с тачскрином. Я запускаю на нём Chrome в Kiosk Mode и хочу, чтобы пользователь терминала мог использовать привычные жесты: например потянул сверху вниз и страница обновилась и т.д. Однако Chrome похоже интерпретирует touchscreen как обычную мышку и соответственно ни жесты, ни скролл пальцем не работают.
На Linux эта проблема решается просто - запуск хрома с ключиком --touch-devices, а что в этом случае можно сделать на Windows?

Answer (score 0):

1. Откройте страницу по адресу `chrome:flags`.
2. Найдите в поиске параметр `#Top-chrome-touch-ui`.
3. Включите его.
4. Перезагрузите браузер.

Comment: Только кнопки большими стали и всё - больше никаких изменений.